# read() from command line returns EISDIR error

Tags: c++, ros

I'm trying to read arrow keys character from the terminal and use the to send `String` type of messages through `ROS`. For doing so I'm using `termios` `read()` function.

Firstly, I have done a small test that works fine under `C`, compiled using `gcc`. This is the code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h> // for keyboard input
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool quit_requested = false;

void processKeyboardInput (char c)
{
   switch (c)
   {
     case 68:// Left arrow pressed
     {
       puts("Left pressed");
       break;
     }
     case 67://Right arrow pressed
     {
       puts("Right pressed");
       break;
     }
     case 65://Up arrow pressed
     {
       puts("Up pressed");
       break;
     }
     case 66://Down arrow pressed
     {
       puts("Down pressed");
       break;
     }
     case 'q'://Quit arrow pressed
     {
       quit_requested = true;
       puts("q pressed, quitting...");
     }
     default:
     {
       break;
     }
 }

}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int key_file_descriptor;
  struct termios raw;
  struct termios original_terminal_state;

  tcgetattr(key_file_descriptor, &original_terminal_state); // get       terminal properties
  memcpy(&raw, &original_terminal_state, sizeof(struct termios));

  raw.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);//local modes, enable canonical mode and echo
  // Setting a new line, then end of file
  raw.c_cc[VEOL] = 1;//special characters
  raw.c_cc[VEOF] = 2;
  tcsetattr(key_file_descriptor, TCSANOW, &raw);

  puts("Reading from keyboard");
  puts("---------------------------");
  puts("Press the arrow keys to move and q to quit");

  char c;
  while (!quit_requested)
  {
    if (read(key_file_descriptor, &c, 1) < 0)
    {
      perror("read char failed():");
      exit(-1);
    }
    processKeyboardInput(c);
  }
      tcsetattr(key_file_descriptor, TCSANOW,      &original_terminal_state);
      puts("Exit");
    return 0;
    }
```

Once done this, I have added `ROS` stuff to send the keys using a `String` message:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h> // for keyboard input
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"


bool quit_requested = false;


std::string processKeyboardInput (char c)
{

   switch (c)
   {
     case 68:// Left arrow pressed
     {
       puts("Left pressed");
       return ("left");
     }
     case 67://Right arrow pressed
     {
       puts("Right pressed");
       return ("right");
     }
     case 65://Up arrow pressed
     {
       puts("Up pressed");
       return ("forward");
     }
     case 66://Down arrow pressed
     {
       puts("Down pressed");
       return ("backward");
     }
     case 'q'://Quit arrow pressed
     {
       quit_requested = true;
       puts("q pressed, quitting...");
     }
     default:
     {
       return ("");
     }
 }

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  std::string cmd;
  int key_file_descriptor;
  char c;
  int error;
  struct termios raw;
  struct termios original_terminal_state;
  //std::string name = "key_teleop";

  /**** INIT ROS STUFFS  *****/
  ros::init(argc, argv, "key_teleop");
  std_msgs::String msg;
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Publisher key_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("key_teleop", 1000);
  ros::Rate loop_rate(1);
  /***************************/

  tcgetattr(key_file_descriptor, &original_terminal_state); // get terminal properties
  memcpy(&raw, &original_terminal_state, sizeof(struct termios));

  raw.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);//local modes, enable canonical mode and echo
  // Setting a new line, then end of file
  raw.c_cc[VEOL] = 1;//special characters
  raw.c_cc[VEOF] = 2;
  tcsetattr(key_file_descriptor, TCSANOW, &raw);

  puts("Reading from keyboard");
  puts("---------------------------");
  puts("Press the arrow keys to move and q to quit");


  while (ros::ok() & (!quit_requested))
  {
  //if (read(key_file_descriptor, &c, 1) < 0)
    error = read(key_file_descriptor, &c, 1);
    if ( error < 0)//Process the error
    {//TODO I get errors, not ROSify code doesn't, C / C++ code mixture issue??
      if (error == EAGAIN)
        puts ("EAGAIN");
      else if (error == EBADF)
        puts ("EBADF");
      else if (error == EFAULT)
        puts ("EFAULT");
      else if (error == EINTR)
        puts ("EINTR");
      else if (error == EINVAL)
        puts ("EINVAL");
      else if (error == EIO)
        puts ("EIO");
      else if (error = EISDIR)
        puts ("EISDIR");
      perror("read char failed():");
      exit(-1);
    }
    cmd = processKeyboardInput(c);
    if (!cmd.empty())
    {
      msg.data = cmd;
      key_pub.publish(msg);
      ros::spinOnce();
      //loop_rate.sleep();
    }
  }
  tcsetattr(key_file_descriptor, TCSANOW, &original_terminal_state);
  puts("Exit");
return 0;
}
```

Once created the `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml`, I have compiled using `catkin_make`. Test it out and now doesn't work, most of the times I receive a error return at `read()`, it enter into `EISDIR` case and prints it. Any idea why now I'm receiving this error while the previous `c` example is working fine??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which line generates the EISDIR error?  The `read()` call in the `main()` in the second example?  You need to test what `errno` is set to — not `error`.  Usually, `error` will be `-1`, which won't match any of the `E*` macros since they're all positive.

Comment: Yes, the `read()` returns a negative value and that's why I have the `case`. It enters into `error= EISDIR` case. I don't get why the first example works and second doesn't.

Comment: You've got an assignment instead of equality typo: `else if (error = EISDIR)
        puts ("EISDIR");`.  I recommend deleting this question, and turning up the compiler warning levels.  If you're using GCC, use at least `-Wall -Werror -Wextra`.  I use more than that, but I've only been programming in C for a bit over 30 years, so I know I don't know all about it (and the options stop me making silly mistakes — like assignments instead of comparisons).  Note that you should not be testing `error`; you might be testing `errno` which would contain the value of an `E*` macro.

Comment: @mugurumov If you add the error-checking code to your first example you will have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the reccomendation of @Jonathan, I have added the flags `-Wall -Werror -Wextra` to the `CMake` compiling flags and discovered the next message thrown by the compiler:

`error: ‘key_file_descriptor’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]`

I have found this [nice article](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/termios) and changed the `int key_file_descriptor`I was using for `STDIN_FILENO`. So I have replaced it all over the code and now is working! I have deleted also the comparison typo. Thanks guys!